# jQuery scrollTo Problem with scrolling two DIVs

Tags: jquery, ajax, scrollto

I've got problems with the jQuery scrollTo plugin. 
I've got 2 DIVs (`nav2` and `content`) and I'm filling them via ajax calls:

```
var myJs = { ...
getWithAjax : function( targetFile, targetDivId, anchorId ) {
    // get is jquery function and wraps ajax call
    $.get(targetFile, function(data) {
        $('#'+targetDivId).html( data );
         if(anchorId !== null){
            myJs.doScrollTo(targetDivId, anchorId);
         }
    });

},

go : function(file1, file2) {
    var file1Array, file2Array = new Array();
    if(file1 !== null){
        file1Array = this.splitLinkFromAnchor(file1);
        // update nav2 div
        this.getWithAjax(file1Array[0], "nav2", file1Array[1]);
    },  //... same with file2 but other div "content" 

doScrollTo : function( divId, anchorId ) {
    $( '#' + divId ).scrollTo( '#' + anchorId, 0 );
}
// ... further functions
} // end of object literal
```

As you see, after getting the content I append it and then try to scroll to a certain position in that target div via an anchorId. This is done via the `doScrollTo`-function that wraps the jQuery-Plugin-function `scrollTo`. `go` is a wrapper for the ajax calls. Before making get-Requests it extracts filename and id (split by '#') from given input parameters.
Here's how this all is called:

`myJs.go( 'file_a.html#anchor1', 'file_b.html#anchor2' );"`

EDIT: With one DIV, the `nav2`DIV, everything works fine. But the other DIV `content` is sometimes scrolled, sometimes not. And also, if it is scrolled and a i move the scrollbar of the DIV up and then call `go` again, it does not scroll anymore. And as I said, this all works fine with the `nav2`DIV...

Anybody got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get(targetFile, function(data) {
    $('#'+targetDivId).html( data );
});
if(anchorId !== null){
        this.doScrollTo(targetDivId, anchorId);
}
```

You're calling `doScrollTo` before the XMLHttpRequest has completed.

That's the whole point of the callback function you pass into `$.get`, it doesn't execute straight away, but only when the asynchronous HTTP request is finished. The `get` method itself returns immediately, so the callback hasn't run and filled in the content by the time you get to the next line with the `if`.

If you want the scroll to happen just after the content is loaded, you need to put that call inside the callback function you're passing to `get`. But note that `this` isn't preserved in callback functions, so you'd have to `bind` it or use a closure:

```
var that= this;
$.get(targetFile, function(data) {
    $('#'+targetDivId).html( data );
    if(anchorId !== null){
        that.doScrollTo(targetDivId, anchorId);
    }
});
```

Comment: thx, that was the solution to the val error.
I mean, that's the way asynchronous call work.... :)
but another misbehaviour still exists => I edited my question.